# JS TypeError while trying to change a color of progressBar

Tags: javascript

html

```
<div class="progress-bar" id="progressBar"></div>
```

script

```
<script>
  function progressBar() {
    let scroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    let height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    let scrolled = scroll / height * 100;
    document.getElementById('progressBar').style.width = scrolled + '%';
    console.log(scrolled);
    if (scrolled == 100);
      progressBar.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
  window.addEventListener('scroll', progressBar);
  </script>
```

I need to change the color of the progressBar from red to green when i scroll to the bottom, but for some reason i get TypeError when i try to change background color

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'backgroundColor')
    at progressBar (index.html:144)
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a variable set for the progressbar element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues

1. Do not use the same name for a function and a variable
2. You did not post the CSS, it must be position fixed to work
3. You had a semicolon after the if to set the bar green

```js
const bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');

function progressBar() {
  let scroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  let height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  let scrolled = scroll / height * 100;
  bar.style.width = scrolled + '%';
  if (scrolled == 100) bar.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', progressBar);
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 0px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar" id="progressBar"></div>
<p>X<br /></p>
<p><br /></p>
<p><br /></p>
<p><br /></p>
<p><br /></p>
<p><br /></p>
<p><br /></p>
<p><br /></p>
<p><br /></p>
<p><br /></p>
<p><br /></p>
<p><br /></p>
<p><br /></p>
<p><br /></p>
<p><br />X</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong here : `if (scrolled == 100);`,remove the semicolon.

Also here `progressBar.style.backgroundColor = "green";` progressBar here is the function not the progress Bar element (DOM element), and also you shouldn't do this `document.getElementById('progressBar').style.width = scrolled + '%';`
instead assign the progress bar element to a variable (**variable's name SHOULD NOT be same as the function**) and then use it inside the function like this:

```
<script>
      let progressBarElement = document.getElementById("progressBar");
      function progressBarFunction() {
        let scroll =
          document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        let height =
          document.documentElement.scrollHeight -
          document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        let scrolled = Math.floor((scroll / height) * 100);

        progressBarElement.style.width = scrolled + "%";
        if (scrolled >= 100)
          progressBarElement.style.backgroundColor = "green";

        console.log(scrolled);
      }
      window.addEventListener("scroll", progressBarFunction);
</script>
```

The style for the progressBar:

```
<style>
   #progressBar {
        position: fixed;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: orange;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: thank you. first of all I'm just a beginner in JavaScript and joined SO to try and solve problems that other people face so I can improve myself.

Comment: I didn't pay attention to you answer before I posted